# How can I further specialize this template idea?

Tags: c++, templates, boost, template-specialization, template-meta-programming

I can do this with a template specialization I think, for nestedness of 1,2,3 (most common cases) by respectively nesting 1,2,3 for loops and referring to the types by their typenames in stl...but for arbitrary depth, without use of the preprocessor, is there a way to do this? Maybe with mpl? Or would I need a preprocessor tool as well? Right now I am doing something like this:

```
template<typename T, int>
struct MapDump {};

template<typename T >
struct MapDump<T,1>
{
  static void dump(const T& map, string file, string header="")
  {
    if (!header.empty())
      cout << header << endl;

    for (typename T::const_iterator cIt = map.begin();
         cIt != map.end();
         ++cIt)
      cout << cIt->first << "," << cIt->second << endl;
  }
};

template<typename T >
struct MapDump<T,2>
{
  static void dump(const T& map, string file, string header="")
  {
    if (!header.empty())
      cout << header << endl;

    for (typename T::const_iterator it1 = map.begin();
         it1 != map.end();
         ++it1)
      for (typename T::mapped_type::const_iterator it2 = it1->second.begin();
           it2 != it1->second.end();
           ++it2)
        cout << it1->first << "," << it2->first << "," << it2->second << endl;
  }
};
```

which I can call with, for example:

```
  map<int, map<int, double> > m;
  m[1][1] = 1.0;
  m[1][2] = 1.0;
  m[2][1] = 2.0;
  m[2][2] = 2.0;

  MapDump< map<int, map<int, double> >, 2 >::dump(m, "test.csv");
```

(I stripped out the fstream stuff and left std::cout to simplify the sample code here) My question is, how can I go about specializing when, say, the last level mapped_type is a container type? For example map > is technically a 2-depth construct and not a one level construct...but my nest of 2 specialization wouldn't compile for that type...any other suggestions on how to, perhaps abstract thsi further (figure out the depth of the construct at compile time as well) are welcome..thanks!

Comment: Can you use c++11 and variadic templates?

Comment: You need to recurse down the nested mapped_types until you reach a dead end and build functors along the way. I'll try to get something going.

Comment: @pmr Yea I sort of though of a recursive down-traversal but i'd have to sit down and think about it harder, how about the nuisance of something like map<int, vector<double> > or map<int, set< vector<int> > > ?

Comment: @jrok I will play with that idea on my laptop at home but where I'm at we unfortunately don't have c++11.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This performs the recursion over all nested types until it reaches a
non-nested type. It uses SFINAE to detect if there is a `mapped_type`
member typedef (You can use `BOOST_HAS_XXX` to create such a helper).

What it does not yet do is do collect the key values and pass them on
to the next level. You can either collect keys in a vector and keep
passing them down or figure out the nesting depth and use an
approximate tuple (this increases compile time complexity to `n^2`).

Do not use `decltype` and the for_each loop, if you want C++03
compatibility.

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

// sfinae to detect a mapped type
template<typename T>
struct has_mapped_type
{ 
private:
  typedef char one;
  typedef struct { char arr[2]; } two;
  template<typename U>
  struct wrap {};

  template<typename U>
  static one test(wrap<typename U::mapped_type>*);

  template<typename U>
  static two test(...);
public:
  static const bool value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == 1;
};


template<typename T, bool has_mapped_type>
// false version
struct dump_impl {
  void operator()(const T& t) const {
    std::cout << t << std::endl;
  }
};

template<typename T>
// true version
struct dump_impl<T, true> 
  : dump_impl<
    typename T::mapped_type
    , has_mapped_type<typename T::mapped_type>::value
  > 
{
  void operator()(const T& t) const {
    for(auto& x : t) { 
      dump_impl<
        typename T::mapped_type
        , has_mapped_type<typename T::mapped_type>::value
        >::
        operator()(x.second);
    }
  }
};

template<typename T>
struct dump : public dump_impl<T, has_mapped_type<T>::value> {
  void operator()(const T& t) const {
    dump_impl<T, has_mapped_type<T>::value>::operator()(t);
  }
};

int main()
{
  std::map<int, std::map<int, double> > m;
  m[1][1] = 1.0;
  m[1][2] = 1.0;
  m[2][1] = 2.0;
  m[2][2] = 2.0;

  dump<decltype(m)>()(m);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Small comment (I have not even read the code :), you can avoid some complexity on the user by letting the compiler infer the types through a function: `template <typename C> dump_map( C const & c ) { dump<C>()(c); }` --I am not sure why the original question prefers a functor over a plain free function... Another nitpick: `_Up` is a reserved identifier, you should not use it in your code. If you meant to say *ignored*, you can use a plain `_`.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas `_Up` happens when your boilerplate SFINAE example comes from the `stdlib`. The deducing function shouldn't be missing in anything close to production.

Comment: This is very cool. I see that dump inherits the appropiate implementation based on the result from has_mapped_type..I'm a bit confused as to how has_mapped_type tests for this though. sizeof(test<T>(0)) gets passed a null pointer of a wrap with template type pointer to the mapped_type...how does that retrieve the size? And what is the purpose of static two test(...)?

Comment: @PalaceChan It is a technique called SFINAE. It is rather arcane, but can be helpful for such tricks. You should have a look at the resources on the web, comments are too limited to explain it.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
template<int I>
struct Int { };

template<typename T, int I>
struct MapDump
{
  static void dump(const T& map, const string& file, const string& header="") {
    if (!header.empty())
      cout << header << endl;
    dump(map, "", Int<I>());
  }

private:
  template<typename Map, int I1>
  static void dump(const Map& map, const string& agg, Int<I1>) {
    for (typename Map::const_iterator cIt = map.begin();
         cIt != map.end();
         ++cIt) {
      dump(cIt->second, (agg + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(
        cIt->first) + ", "), Int<I1-1>());
    }
  }

  template<typename D>
  static void dump(const D& d, const string& agg, Int<0>) {
     cout << agg << d << endl;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple recursive function template that will print the nested maps:

```
template <typename Last>
void dumpMap(const Last &last,const std::string &first)
{
  std::cout << first << last << "\n";
}

template <typename A,typename B>
void dumpMap(const std::map<A,B> &last,const std::string &first=std::string())
{
  typename std::map<A,B>::const_iterator i=last.begin(), i_end=last.end();
  for (;i!=i_end;++i) {
    std::ostringstream s;
    s << first << (*i).first << ",";
    dumpMap((*i).second,s.str());
  }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
map<int, map<int, double> > m;
m[1][1] = 1.0;
m[1][2] = 1.0;
m[2][1] = 2.0;
m[2][2] = 2.0;

dumpMap(m);
```